# Why this two variable's values remain the same after I change one of them?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm studying php and I made this code:

```
$a = new DateTime('NOW');

$b = $a;

$b->modify("+1 day");

echo "<pre>";

print_r($a);    

print_r($b);
```

And in both my `print_r` the results are the same, this:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-12-29 15:05:27.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-12-29 15:05:27.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Use $b = clone $a. In your code both variables point to one object

Comment: Or refactor your code to use `DateTimeImmutable`, that's what it's there for

Comment: I see, thank you. Can you explain to me what exactly "point to one object" means, or give me a link where I can study about it?